# remove "The SAS System" from SAS the log

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Is there a way that will remove

> the sas system

from Log?
`title;` or `title '';` i still can see this lable in log

Comment: In Log, or in Output?  `title;` or `title ' ';` (with a space) should remove the `The SAS System` title from the output.

Comment: Yep, the question how to remove it from the log?

Comment: I don't see it in the log, so I don't know what you're asking.  Moreover, why would you need to remove it from the log?

Comment: The sas program stores log in a file and it cosists of many line, can be about of million... But after each 40 lines i recieve this senseless message "The SAS System"

Comment: Ah, okay; in EG there is such a thing, didn't notice that tag originally.

Comment: yep, you can find it in eg also when using scl language

Answer (score 2):

You can limit how frequently the page breaks occur by going to Tools -> Options -> Results General and setting the PS (page size) to 32767 (the max legal value).  That will reduce them significantly.  Not sure if there's a way to remove it entirely.

Comment: can i do it in sas code that i will use it not ony with EG?

Comment: Also a good idea to post this q to communities.sas.com as some of the Devs post there

Comment: To change the PAGESIZE (alias PS) or LINESIZE (alias LS) option use the OPTIONS statement in SAS code.   `options ps=32767;`